# How to control what happens when a user puts their email in the text field and clicks submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am making a task list on my site, in which i will put different things to do..

In the end they will be asked to put in their email address and click submit.

Now This is what I want to do when they click submit:

- The next day,(not right away!) they should get an email that should
  link them to next task.
- This should be automatic, and I just have to set the submit buttons
  up with the right code provided by you.

It will be my great honor if a volunteer helps me out.

I am also using wordpress

Comment: This should be BE solution. You can't do this only using JS

Comment: You'll need some server side code, and a chron job. Have the chron job trigger the server side code everyday, fetch all the data relating to the previous day, then loop through it and send one email per task.

Comment: there will be at least 30 tasks, and different people will start doing them at different days.

Comment: Have you looked for an appropriate Wordpress plugin?  This a place to ask specific questions, not look for volunteers.

Comment: I can't look up a plugin if i don't know what terms to search for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using JavaScript and Java Servlets.
in action page call: action servlet.
Servlet Should be able to send the email at particular time.

[How to send email automatically at particular time of day in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421288/how-to-send-email-automatically-at-particular-time-of-day-in-java)[Click here to see how to send an email at particular time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421288/how-to-send-email-automatically-at-particular-time-of-day-in-java)

[Try this too](http://www.java4s.com/core-java/send-java-email-in-specific-time-interval-automatically-dynamically/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with just javascript. You will need that form to post to some back end server which can store the information (probably in a database), and process it at some point in the future when it is necessary.

Comment: @MohammadDohadwala Learn some technology like Java, ASP.NET, Ruby on Rails or PHP.

Comment: without knowing which server language you're using, we can't give you an answer to that.

Comment: Lol, that would take a long time to learn. 
BTW is it hard to do something simple like this?

Comment: I am using WordPress, i think they use PHP and mySQL

Comment: yeah, you can do this pretty easily using php and mysql. look around for examples on the web.

Comment: what terms should i search for?